# Convergence proof of sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that the sequence $a(n):= \frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges.
Therefore I've shown that a(n+1)<a(n):

$\frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}=\frac{n+1)!}{n+1)^(n+1)}\cdot\frac{n^n}{n!}=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}<1$

and because this is smaller than one the sequence is monotonously decreasing.

Next I have to show that the sequence is limited from below, which overall would mean that the sequence converges.
Indeed I don't really know how to go on here.
Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: It is bounded below by $0$.

Comment: $n!/n^n\le 1/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that $a_n \leq 1$, but it is also true that $a_n >0$. So, you have that $0 < a_n \leq 1$. Since the sequence is bounded and monotonous, it is convergent. Using Stirling's formula, you also see that
$$
\lim \frac{n!}{n^n} = \lim \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}{e^n} = 0.
$$